# OpenLayers 3 - style cache and memory usage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching, openlayers-3

I have an OL3 app with a vector layer that has a style function that makes expensive computations for creating the ol.style.Style objects for each feature. More precisely, each point has an icon that is created dynamically, plus some text (name of the point) if the map is zoomed in past a certain level. It's creating the icon that takes times, therefore I use a cache for the ol.style.Style objects. It works extremely well to reduce the initial map load time (huge difference), because in practice there are not too many possible styles, and therefore everytime a point is going to share the same style, the computation/conversion of image to produce the icon is skipped and the style is retrieved from the cache. (For the case when the names are shown, it might be less useful, because probably most points will have a different name, but it can still be useful if the user pans the map and then returns to the same location, or zooms in, out, and then in again. Anyway there does not seem to be a performance problem since, as I noticed, OpenLayers only renders the points that are currently visible in the view.)

However, I am wondering how much memory this cache really uses. First, I tried a couple of libraries found on the web that allow you to get the total size of a JavaScript variable, but they would not work on my cache, maybe because there are too many sub-properties, or cases they do not handle. Next, I tried the Google Chrome dev tools, and used the "Take heap snapshot" feature, and the cache size I find is surprisingly low. It seems that my styleCache takes only 704 bytes (retained size) per ol.style.Style object (actually each of them is alone in an Array, because the style function has to return an array, and I put the array directly in the cache).

So, two questions here :

1. I noticed that the total retained size of objects using that tool can be smaller than the sum of their properties/sub-objects. Do you know why ? Is this tool a reliable way of measuring the memory in use ?
2. Does OpenLayers have its own internal cache of icon images ? I noticed that there is an ol.style.IconImageCache object too... This could explain why my cache does not take much memory, since the images would be shared when possible too. This would mean that the computation of the icon image must still be done for each point (because there is no way the ImageIconCache could guess that the icon image will be the same as one it already holds), but it still helps reducing the memory usage.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added (I cannot edit questions yet) that if my hypothesis is right, the size of my cache is less than expected because the icons are actually stored in OL's built-in IconImageCache (more importantly than the sharing of icons). Is my understanding correct ?